# Merge every second cell with xlsxwriter

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I wish to merge every second cell with xlsxwriter like below.

[image]

I've tried this

```
import xlsxwriter, os, datetime as dt

# Create an new Excel file and add a worksheet.
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('AARs.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Create a format to use in the merged range.
merge_format = workbook.add_format({
    'align': 'center',
    'valign': 'vcenter'})

# Start and end dates of the trial to go into the spreadsheet.
start_date = dt.datetime(2019, 8, 6)
end_date = dt.datetime(2019, 12, 13)
trial_length = end_date -start_date

# Merge cells.
for days in range(trial_length.days):
    worksheet.merge_range(1, 1+days, 1, 2+days, 'Merged Range', merge_format)

workbook.close()
```

I have explicitly written out the for loop below

```
worksheet.merge_range(1, 1, 1, 2, 'Merge Range', merge_format)
worksheet.merge_range(1, 3, 1, 4, 'Merge Range', merge_format)
worksheet.merge_range(1, 5, 1, 6, 'Merge Range', merge_format)
worksheet.merge_range(1, 7, 1, 8, 'Merge Range', merge_format)
worksheet.merge_range(1, 9, 1, 10, 'Merge Range', merge_format)
worksheet.merge_range(1, 11, 1, 12, 'Merge Range', merge_format)
worksheet.merge_range(1, 13, 1, 14, 'Merge Range', merge_format)
worksheet.merge_range(1, 15, 1, 16, 'Merge Range', merge_format)
worksheet.merge_range(1, 17, 1, 18, 'Merge Range', merge_format)
worksheet.merge_range(1, 19, 1, 20, 'Merge Range', merge_format)
```

I am now just having trouble writing the correct loop. I have tried something like:

```
count_odd = 0
count_even = 0
for days in range(trial_length.days):
    if not days % 2:
        worksheet.merge_range(1, 1, 1, 2 + count_even, 'Merge Range', merge_format)
        count_even += 1
    else:
        worksheet.merge_range(1, 1 + count_odd, 1, 2 + count_even, 'Merge Range', merge_format)
        count_odd += 1
```

but this also doesn't seem to work.
I'm trying to merge every second cell.

Comment: What do _it looks ok_ and _it doesn't look right_ mean?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I added how it appears in Linux

Comment: If I’m understanding this correctly, won’t `days + 1` be the same as the previous iteration’s `days + 2`?

Comment: Forgot to mention that variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

```
odd = 1
even = 2
for day in range(trial_length.days):
    worksheet.merge_range(1, odd, 1, even, 'Merge Range', merge_format)
    odd += 2
    even += 2
```

Answer was almost too obvious.